# Set title labels of buttons in table view from an array full of strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I was making this table view inside my view controller. The table view was going to have a set of buttons. Now I have an array which contains labels for those buttons, but the button labels are only set to the first object in the array.

How do I set their labels to their respective object in the array i.e. second button gets second object as label, and so on? Here is what I've been doing.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"celllIdentifier";
    UIButton *btnProblem;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        btnProblem = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnProblem = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,0,635,75)];

       [btnProblem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sc123_button_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
       [btnProblem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sc123_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"RobotoSlab-Regular" size:25];
        //[btnProblem setTitle:[btnLabels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [btnProblem.titleLabel setFont:font];
        btnProblem.tag = 1000;
        [cell addSubview:btnProblem];
        cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    btnProblem  = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    return cell;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_btnNext addTarget:self action:@selector(btnNextTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnLabels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Lime-scale on fixtures",@"Spots on dishes",@"Clothing becomes gray after washing",@"Clothing feels stiff or wrinkles easily in wash",@"Rings form in toilet or where water stands",@"Misting system clogs", @"Faucets don’t have even spray",@"Valves have white deposits at connections", nil];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [btnLabels count];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
[btnProblem setTitle:[btnLabels[indexPath.section] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

instead of this -

```
[btnProblem setTitle:[btnLabels[indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

As there are only one row in each section, to access array's object use section number. 
p.s also uncomment the above line of code.

Comment: Thank you that worked! I get it now! Row remains 0 but it's the section that is changing from 0 to 7.