# How to shove a label in a tableview full of buttons?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view full of buttons. A label is outside the tableview serving as heading. I want to shove it inside the table view, on top of course, without changing it to button. In other words I want to move it inside the tableview, but on top and not as a button,as a heading. 
The label in question says "Select all things that apply to your home"

For code please see [Set title labels of buttons in table view from an array full of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780069/set-title-labels-of-buttons-in-table-view-from-an-array-full-of-strings)

For Screenshot pls visit http://i60.tinypic.com/2qmf4wl.png

Comment: Why not use the header view property of UITableView instead of an external label for it?

Comment: you mean making a section and setting it's text value?

Comment: Because I did not know about headerview...till now.

Comment: No Tudoric, headerview is what i wanted. I just did not know what to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
UIView *headerView;
UILabel *labelView;

labelView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
labelView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:22.0];
labelView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
labelView.text = @"* Your important note here.";
labelView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[headerView addSubview:labelView];
yourTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to add a label to a tableviewcontroller. Two options I can think of:

1. Make "Select all things that apply to your home" your navigation item title. (you can do this right in the storyboard)
2. Place a table view in a normal view controller and leave enough space on top for a label. (again, you can drag a normal table view into a view controller in a storyboard)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can creat a subclass of UITableViewCell and custom the cell for the tabe